# Leaving Croatia if I have a Type D visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, long-stay-visas, croatia

I am from India. It's been more than 4 months since I came to Croatia. My work permit was issued for one year, but the employer I came to work for told me to work for him for 1 month and then find another job because the session is over here. My TRC (Temporary Residence Card) also has not been generated.  I have been looking for a job here, but I have not found one yet. What should I do if I want to go back to my country? Will there be any problems at immigration?

Comment: If you haven't overstayed the visa, then you shouldn't have any problem leaving the country. Is that the answer you are looking for? What problems are you anticipating?

Comment: Sir I just want to know that till now my TRC card is not generated because I have not got any job here I have single entry D type visa. Or I have been in Croatia for 4 months now want to go back to India so will I have to face any problem in immigration at airport like fine etc or any jail etc.

Comment: Just to be clear - You overstayed for 4 months. Now you want to leave?

Comment: sir it was my first time abroad from india i didn't know now someone has said to find out but in embassy they are not giving any response my visa sticker is written to stay for equal period 30 days. sir what should i do now i have overstayed

Comment: See the below answer. You should leave the country and return home as soon as possible.

Comment: sir if i go to india now i will face any problem in immigration like jail and fines.

Comment: India won't take any action against you. Croatia shouldn't take, as long as you leave voluntarily. Need to confirm that. Let me find any references

Comment: This might help - https://www.expatincroatia.com/services/

Comment: I have to face some problem at the time of immigration at Croatia airport, please let me know, it will be very kind of you

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure. You can try contacting the above site. They seems to provide professional advice.

Comment: See this - https://fra.europa.eu/sites/default/files/fra-2014-criminalisation-of-migrants-annex_en.pdf Check the Croatia page. It says fine may be waived for minor offences like yours.

Comment: @AnishSheela why do you conclude that Mohammad shoraab has overstayed?  Mohammad shoraab, when does your type D visa expire?

Comment: @phoog i dont know about the expired of the D type visa I just google and see this line.       
   Enclosed documents for a long-term visa (visa D)
Long-term visa (visa D) is issued for one (1) or multiple (MULT) entries, with the period of validity no longer than six months and for maximum 30-days' stay. Application shall be submitted prior to the entry into Croatia, at the competent Embassy/Consulate.

Comment: @Mohammadshoraab you can find the expiration date of your type D visa printed on the visa itself.  Also, is your work permit a separate document from the type D visa?  If so, it should also have an expiration date.  If it does, what is the date?

Comment: @phoog Sir I have work permit for 1 year but I don't have Croatian temporary residence card because employer didn't make it.  And the visa printed on my passport is the day of stay of 30 days written single entry

Comment: @Mohammad shoraab For a moment, forget about the duration of your "work permit", and forget about the TRC. Only concentrate on you D visa for now. Look at the expiry date of the visa and tell us what is the expiry date.

Answer (score 2):

Your circumstances are not entirely clear, so I'll rewrite the answer, sticking to the most basic facts.

As an Indian citizen, you are not going to face any problems when entering India. Your stay in Croatia violated no Indian laws.

Whether or not will you face any problems in Croatia / EU depends on whether or not you violated any immigration laws there. If you're not overstaying your visa / residence permit, you needn't worry. If you are overstaying, you might face a fine, but the fine is frequently waived for minor immigration offences when the person leaves voluntarily (i.e. is not deported). However, each overstaying is recorded and you might be denied a future Croatia / Schengen Area visa.

Hope this helps!